# Navmesh agent cannot walk through some parts of his path

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have a cube, that defines the destination for navmesh agent. There are no problems when my character walks to his destination for the first time. But then i randomly change the position of my destination object, and the path my agent should go to his next destination becomes light-blue and starts blinking, and agent now cannot walk through it. There are some screenshots:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDIPD.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC36P.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verfiy that the new "random" position is a valid navmesh position?

I also noticed that the cube has a collider, try to turn that off since it could disturb the pathfinding.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.